# retriving my contacts

Tags: contacts

I restored my phone sonny xperia E5 to factory settings then after I sinned in with my google account but I am unable to synchronize my contacts please help me my contacts are saved in google account

Comment: what kind of help do you expect?

Answer (score -1):

Hi and thanks for your question on

## How to Retrieve Lost Contacts from Google

I hope this screenshot I grabbed from Google will help you:
[image: Step Guide on Restoring Contacts from Google]

And here's a written summary of the steps:

Go to your device settings and choose 'Google'.

Under 'Services,' select 'Restore Contacts' (tap 'From Account' if you have more than one account and need to specify which you want to restore)

Then tap the device with the contacts to copy and select which contacts specifically you would like to copy

Lastly just hit "Restore" and wait til you see the "Contacts Restored!" message.  These will sync automatically.

For contacts in other apps like Outlook, you will need to re-download those apps and follow their procedures.

Again, I hope this helps!  Have a great day!

Comment: Please paste the text from the source in a quoted format, instead of a screenshot. It's much better, and also allows searching.